# Testing console.log in catch block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, jestjs, mocking

I have the following code:

loggerManager.js:

```
export default log(message) {
  try {
    axios.post(...).catch(error) { console.log(error); }
  }catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

loggerManager.test.js:

```
test('', () => {
  jest.spyOn(global.console, 'log');
  jest.mock('axios');
  axios.post = jest.fn(() => Promise.reject('fail'));
  log('message');
  expect(console.log).toBeCalledWith('fail'); // The result said it has not been called even once
});
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What makes you think you are? What are you seeing / not seeing that you don't expect to see / expect to see?

Comment: I expect to see the catch block call the console.log. I am sorry, i hope i got your question right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. A rejection handler converts rejection into fulfillment if it doesn't `throw` or return a promise that is rejected
2. `try`/`catch` doesn't catch promise rejections except when the promise is consumed via `await` within the `try` block

So assuming the normal case, if your `axios.post`'s promise rejects, the rejection handler runs but the `catch` block does not.

In this code:

```
export default log(message) {
  try {
    axios.post(...).catch(error) { console.log(error); }
  }catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Execution will only go into the `catch` block at the end if:

- `axios` is an undeclared identifier; or
- `axios` doesn't have a `post` property; or
- `axios.post` isn't a function; or
- `axios.post` throws when called; or
- `axios.post` doesn't return an object with a `catch` property; or
- The `catch` property of the object `axios.post` returns isn't a function; or
- The `catch` method of the object `axios.post` returns throws when called

It will **not** be entered if `axios.post` returns a promise that is rejected.

You may have wanted this:

```
export default async log(message) {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^
  try {
    await axios.post(...);
// −^^^^^
  }catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

That way, the `catch` block will be entered if there was a problem calling `axios.post` *or* if `axios.post` returns a promise that is rejected.

Comment: FWIW, I go into promises and `async`/`await` in some detail in Chapters 8 and 9 of my new(ish) book, *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but even with the async/await added, the console.log in the catch block is still not triggered

Comment: I will check out your book too!

Comment: @AKJ - Sounds like the `post` is successful. :-) You might want a success handler.

Comment: How could it be successful though when the axios.post is stictly set to return Promise.reject()?

Comment: @AKJ - I don't know. But if it returns a rejected promise or a promise that will reject, your original rejection handler would have been called, as would the one in the `async` version above.

Comment: @AKJ - I see you've accepted the answer. Did you find out what was going on?